# Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-emulator

I am working with Flutter and `FirebaseFireStore`, everything is perfect in the first time.
But when I restart and re-build, I got this error

> W/DynamiteModule( 3465): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found. 
> I/TetheringManager( 3465): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.mtlu_brew_crew 
> I/DynamiteModule( 3465): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0 W/ProviderInstaller( 3465): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

I tried some solution but it is still not working:

- update Google play service of emulator
- add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]